# Javascript override Request.Form("foo") for security (XSS)

Tags: security, asp-classic, xss, jscript

I've got some source code that has some cross site scripting vulnerabilities in it. There is no input validation that happens when the browser sends data over to the server which is executing server-side Javascript and classic ASP (IIS 7.0).

My question is, is there a way to override the `Request.Form("foo")` object/method so that I can call a sanitization function too and get rid of prohibited JS/HTML? I don't want to do a find and replace on every single file everywhere `Request.Form` is called. I was hoping for something more elegant.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `var oldRequestForm = Request.Form; Request.Form = function(param) { return yourSanitization(oldRequestForm(param))}`

Comment: I just did. Didn't work.

Comment: @JuanMendes No, not possible. Try _search_ and _replace all_ instead of _find_ and _replace_.

Comment: There is nothing not elegant about a global find and replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can change `Request.Form` members.

What you can do, as a partial solution, is to create a code that will run first on every page (for example, using an `include` directive) which loops over `Request.Form`, `Request.QueryString` etc., and if it finds suspected code, it terminates the code execution (`Response.End`). This solution is partial because it doesn't really sanitize input, it just drops execution when it finds suspected text.

**Another option:** Create an array, parallel to `Request.Form`. Populate this array with the same members as in Request.Form, but this time sanitized. Then, quickly do a Find-and-Replace over your whole code base, and change `Request.Form` to your custom array variable.

Comment: OP doesn't want to use a Find/Replace, which I think is a better option. I like your suggestion of an include that loops over `Request.Form` at the top of the page

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to replace the whole `Request` object with another COM object but its an insane solution and it would still require that all ASP files that use `Form` contain a common top include file.  Its not possible to replace the `Request` object or one of its members globally at the application level.

The correct solution to the problem, your statement "don't want to do a find and replace on every single file everywhere" notwithstanding, is to perform such global replace.

Despite the number of .asp files that exist the cost is no more than knocking up a simple program to open each ASP file in a folder tree, adding an include line and replacing `Request.Form`.